# Eclipse RCP4 close Part on exit / disable persistence of a Part?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

i'm working on an Eclipse RCP4 project. I have different perspectives showing a set of Parts to choose informations from. After selecting what i want to see, a new Part opens and displays the objet i want to edit / view attibutes of.
I can open many parts of the same type. If i close the application, the eclipse framwork persists the position of all opened Parts. If i restart the application all previously opened Parts are open but without informations.

-How to prevent Eclipseframwork from persisting the state of Parts?

-How to close Parts on exit?

I'm searching for a way to add an "removeOnExit" tag to a Part and than close such a marked Part on exit.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would it be an option to switch layout persistence in the  ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor of, using configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this you can close MParts with a specific Tag.

It seems you have to switch to the Perspective the Part is on, else it's not removed from the context wich will cause nullpointer exceptions.

```
@Inject
    @Optional
    public void doEvent(@EventTopic(EventConstants.EventTopics.CLOSE_PARTS_WITH_TAGS) String tagToClose, MApplication app,


EModelService eModelService, EPartService ePartService) {
    MUIElement activePart = ePartService.getActivePart();
    EPartService activePeServcie = null;
    MPerspective activePerspective = null;
    if (activePart instanceof MPart) {
        activePeServcie = ((MPart) activePart).getContext().get(EPartService.class);
        activePerspective = eModelService.getPerspectiveFor(activePart);
    }

    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    tags.add(tagToClose);
    List<MPart> elementsWithTags = eModelService.findElements(app, null, MPart.class, tags);

    for (MPart part : elementsWithTags) {
        try {
            logger.info("Closing part " + part.toString());
            EPartService peService = part.getContext().get(EPartService.class);
            peService.switchPerspective(eModelService.getPerspectiveFor(part));
            peService.hidePart(part);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    if (activePart instanceof MPart && activePeServcie != null && activePerspective != null) {
        activePeServcie.switchPerspective(activePerspective);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We too tried to migrate from Eclipse 3 to Eclipse 4.We used the comp layer and had a lot of problems with the migration. I had a similar problem with persistent store of the eclipse workbench. So parts and views had the same position as before restart.

The persistence paradigma in Eclipse 4 has changed. Please take a look [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/17/saveandrestore-e4/):

As far as I remember the call of `configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false)` does not work in Eclipse 4 correctly.